# Kivy call methods from different classes

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a button and two sliders in my sample `.kv` file:

```
<intLab>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 10
        orientation: "horizontal"

        FREQslider:
            id: s2
            color: 1,0.5,1,1
            value: 20
            orientation: 'vertical'
            max: 300
            min: 20
            size_hint_x: None
            width: '48dp'
            step: 1
            on_value: root.onFrequencySlide(self.value)

        AMPLslider:
            id: s3
            color: 1,.5,.5,0
            value: 1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            max: 100
            min: 0
            size_hint_x: None
            width: '48dp'
            step: 1
            on_value: root.onAmplitudeSlide(self.value)

        ToggleButton:
            id: 'enableBtn'
            text: 'Enable' if self.state == 'normal' else 'Disable'
            state: 'normal'
            on_release: root.on_disable()
```

In the `.py` file I have two classes. The class which corresponds to the `.kv` structure, `intLab` and another class `KivyCamera`.

```
class intLab(BoxLayout):

    def init_intlab(self):
        pass

    def on_disable(self):
        self.updateFreqAmpl(0, 0)
        self.ids.s2.value = 20
        self.ids.s3.value = 0
```

From the kivy UI when I press the `disable` button, the `updateFreqAmpl` method is called and both sliders are set to 20 and 0, respectively, so this works.

However, if I call the `on_disable` method from the `KivyCamera` class then even though the `updateFreqAmpl` method is called, the slider values do not change, but no error is given.

Here is how I call the `on_disable` method from the `KivyCamera` class:

```
class KivyCamera(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = None

    def update(self, dt):
        t = intLab()
        intLab.on_disable(t)
```

Please note that this is simplified example, but I have captured the core details.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new **instance** of *intLab* instead if using the existing one.

```
def update(self, dt):
    t = intLab() #creating a new one == :(
    intLab.on_disable(t)
```

You need to access the **existing** *intLad* **instance** ,,,

Comment: It makes no sense to call `intLab.on_disable(t)` if your advice not to assign a new instance to `t`. With the `t` removed I get this error `TypeError: unbound method on_disable() must be called with intLab instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Comment: You should access it another way,  for example, *ugly way*,keep a global reference to it

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example. I do not know how you mean. Thanks

Comment: in the \__init__ of intLab, just write: global t;t=self #now you have access to it from anywhere ...(this is not a good practice though)